# Deny particular users (that are part of domain) from site

Tags: access-denied, access

We need to block some users who may have access to our site.

They are about to be added to the domain group by our IT department that has been given permission to view the site but it has hundreds of users and would be preferable if we could just block a few users rather than going down another route.

I have done a bit of searching and seen a code to enter for this but I'm not particularly experienced in this field (I have inserted HTML to remove the 'Recently Modified' link but not much else). Not sure if this code needs entered on the first page, the parent page (which is a different page to our main page) or each and every page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to break inheritance from the parent site and giving unique permissions for you particular site.

Steps to break permission inheritance

> 1. Browse to the Site Permissions page for a site (choose Site
>      Actions→Site Settings→Site Permissions).
>
>    The Site Permissions page is displayed with a message reading This
>      Web site inherits permissions from its parent.
>
>    2. Click the Stop Inheriting Permissions button in the Permission Tools
>         tab Edit group.
>
>    A message window appears reading, in part, You are about to create
>      unique permissions for this Web site.
>
>    3. Click OK.
>
>    The Site Permissions page is displayed with a message reading, This
>      Web Site has unique permissions.
>
>    The site’s permissions levels and SharePoint groups are no longer
>      Read Only.
>
>    4. Click the Grant Permissions button on the Ribbon to grant
>         permissions to users and groups.
>
>    The Grant Permissions dialog box appears.
>
>    5. In the Select Users section, enter the SharePoint Group you want to
>         grant permissions to access the site, list, or library.
>
>    This is where you want to use your SharePoint Groups — Site Members,
>      Site Visitors, or Site Owners. What if users are in your group that
>      you don’t want to have permissions to the subsite, list, or library?
>      You need to create a new SharePoint group and grant that group
>      permission to the subsite, list, or library.
>
>    6. In the Grant Permissions section, select the Grant Users Permissions
>         Directly radio button.
>    7. Select the permission level that matches the permissions you want to
>         grant.
>
>    The default permission levels for team sites are Full Control,
>      Design, Contribute, and Read. You can create your own permissions
>      levels by clicking the Permission Levels button on the Ribbon if you
>      need additional groups of permissions.
>
>    8. Click OK.

[Source](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/break-inheritance-permissions-in-sharepoint-2010-t.html)

Comment: Thanks for that @vishwas-goswami but that won't solve the issue. We have already broke inheritence from the parent. Our site is quite big with lots of information on it so we already use permission groups for some of it. But there's alot of staff that need access to the whole site. Once these new users are added to that domain group we want a way to block the few rather than set up groups for the many.